# Does Firebase send ALL the data under a given path?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, nosql, denormalization

I'm a little confused as to how much data is automatically fetched by Firebase and I'm having a hard time modeling data.

As I understand it, an authenticated user's ID is compared to the path; if the key is missing, the path is inaccessible. In addition, once a path is called, all of the data within it is accessed.

For instance, fetching `/cart/<$uid>/<item>` would also include $uid1, $uid, $uid3 ... $uidN, etc. So if I were to nest all of the data under `/<$uid>`, like:

`/<$uid>/cart`

`/<$uid>/orders`

`/<$uid>/transactions`

Does this mean that fetching `/<$uid>/cart` also returns all those other keys? What if I only call `<$uid>`?

If the structure is instead by `cart/` or `orders/` first, does this mean all the orders for all the users are fetched?

In other words, when a user logs in, I'd like to retrieve the contents of (using one of those "schemas") the cart:

```
// Fires onAuthStateChanged()
firebaseListener(function authStateChange(loggedIn, user) {
  if (store) {
    if (user) {
      store.dispatch('getShoppingCart', { uid: user.uid, currentCart: store.getters.cartItemList });
      store.dispatch('setUser', user);
    }
  }
})
```

`getShoppingCart` then runs something similar to:

```
let ref = db.ref('/cart/' + store.state.uid + '/')
ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  store.cart.concat(snapshot)
})
```

Comment: Please add some (pseudo) code to explain what you mean with fetching in this case.

Comment: @AndréKool Exactly as simple as that; my question is more about designing schema. If cart goes first and userID is second, does that mean accessing the path this way will mean every child users cart will at least be considered if not in the snapshot?

Comment: I think you are confusing security rules (the $uid wildcard) and actual reading/writing in firebase here. Can you maybe link to where you are getting this from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user logs in, you are retrieving the information of that user, so when you use `uid`, you are retrieving the id of that login user.

When you use this `ref('/cart/' + store.state.uid + '/')` it will go to `cart` node first and then the `uid` of that user and not all userids who are under carts.

You can also use `once('value').then(function(snapshot) {` which will only read the data once and not trigger again.